# Специфическая настройка mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite

Здравствуйте
Пробую перенастроить работу сайта (интернет магазина), там много регионов и переключение между ними осуществляется через параметр ссылки http://site.ru/?region=kyiv

Но я хочу перенести отдельные города на поддомены и чтобы перепись ссылок была приблизительно такая:
    http://site.ru/?region=kyiv на http://kyiv.site.ru/
    http://site.ru/some_category-7/?region=kyiv на http://kyiv.site.ru/some_category-7/
    http://site.ru/some_category-7/some_good.html?region=kyiv на  http://kyiv.site.ru/some_category-7/some_good.html

Таких городов есть несколько.Спасибо.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, сходу не скажу, скоро отвечу.

Comment: pyatak, я все еще надеюсь на Вашу версию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} region\=(.+) RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          http://%1.test.ru/$1 [R]
```